# Html parser package in React (react-html-parser) is stripping <script> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my React app I am using [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser).

And use it like:

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

<div>
  {ReactHtmlParser(html)}
</div>
```

From the backend I get some `html`:

(function(... a custom function here --->);

But if I check the `dom` everything is rendered, except the `<script>` tag?

I tried the suggestion from [this thread](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser/issues/98):

```
import ReactHtmlParser, { Options } from 'react-html-parser';

const options = {
    replace: (domNode: { type: string; attribs: { src: string } }) => {
      if (domNode.type === 'script') {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = domNode.attribs.src;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      }
    },
  };

return (
    <div>
      {ReactHtmlParser(html, options as Options)}
    </div>
  );
```

But it's still not injecting the script?

**Update**
Trying the answer from @Nemanja. Due to Typescript I had to change it a bit:

```
const transform: Transform = (node, index) => {
    if (node.type === 'script' && node.children?.length) {
      console.log('Node', node);
      return <script key={index}>{node.children[0].data}</script>;
    }
    return null;
  };

  const options = {
    transform,
  };
```

But now its not rendering the actual HTML anymore?

Comment: Did you tried solution I posted in aswer?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer for typescript.

Comment: I updated answer to include code for react-html-parser. You can use both, but for me htm-react-parser is easier to use and it has better documentation.

Comment: I don't see the reason why my answer is not accepted.

Comment: Ok, I updated answer. Code below should behave as you described.

Comment: @mezz it won't work since you are returning null for all dom elements that are not type script. That's why you don't see any other elements than script renderend in DOM.

Comment: @mezz What is exacly the problem with my answer?

Comment: what typescript issues? The code I posted is written in typescript and it compiles without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a script, you will need to programmatically create and append a script element using `transfom` method from `react-html-parser` library.
Code below shoud work as expected.

```
import React, { DOMElement } from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser, { Options } from "react-html-parser";



 const html =
   "<div class='css-class' data-src='/event/66478667'></div>  <script src='something'>(function(d, s, id) {var js,ijs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='https://embed.widget.js';ijs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ijs);}(document, 'script', 'my-js'));</script>";


  const options = {
    transform : function transform(node :any, index:any) {
       if ( node.type === 'script') {
          return <script key={index} src={node?.attribs?.src}>{node?.children[0]?.data}</script>;
      }
    }
  };



export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {ReactHtmlParser(html, options as Options)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the output of following code :

[image]

Comment: @meez I updated picture in my answer. I tried the code above and everythig is working as expected.